# how to activate section Index Titles For Table View

Tags: iphone

this is my first question here..

I have a tableview setting with numberOfSectionsInTableView=6, which has also custom created cells.
I am trying to use 'section index title' with some predefined titles . I have gone through sample code and following the same.
I'm able to show section index title from my tableview by using function 'sectionIndexTitlesForTableView'. 
But to activate that, i don't know how to make it work when i clicked on some title. Let me want to move to the page based on title selection.
For example, same like how built-in Contacts(address book) works.

I'm on MAC OS X 10.7 lion (beta)
using XCode 4.2 iOS SDK 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:` !

> This method is passed the index number
>   and title of an entry in the section
>   index list and should return the index
>   of the referenced section. To be
>   clear, there are two index numbers in
>   play here: an index to an section
>   index title in the array returned by
>   sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:, and
>   an index to a section of the table
>   view; the former is passed in, and the
>   latter is returned. You implement this
>   method only for table views with a
>   section index list—which can only be
>   table views created in the plain style
>   (UITableViewStylePlain). Note that the
>   array of section titles returned by
>   sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: can
>   have fewer items than the actual
>   number of sections in the table view.